# tooltip function getTip() not working on actioncolumn Extjs 7.X

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect

The tooltip function getTip is not working for me.

I initialized `Ext.tip.QuickTipManager.init();` in my app.json launch function.

My actioncolumn is looking like this:

```
xtype: 'actioncolumn',
getTip: function(value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
    return "something";
},
flex: 0.75,
style: 'text-align: left;',
width: 25,
align: 'center',
menuDisabled: true,
bind: {
    text: '{filename}'
},
items: [
    {
        handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row) {
            Application.fireEvent("filefunction", view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row);
        },
        getClass: function(v, metadata, r, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
        return "x-far fa-file-alt";
        },
        iconCls: 'x-far fa-file-alt'
    }
]
```

It does not call the getTip() function at all. What am i doing wrong?

The docs:

[getTip() Documentation by Sencha](https://docs-devel.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.grid.column.Action.html#cfg-getTip)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getTip` function will only work if your action column does not have `items`, only a single icon. For example, modifying your code like this **does display** the tooltip:

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    // this works with items, with one icon
    getTip: function(value, metadata, record, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
        return "something";
    },
    iconCls: 'x-far fa-file-alt',
    flex: 0.75,
    style: 'text-align: left;',
    width: 25,
    align: 'center',
    menuDisabled: true,
    bind: {
        text: '{filename}'
    },
}
```

If you have multiple items in the action column, you **have to define tooltip separately for each item**. You can set the tooltip for one item in the action column using the `tooltip` configuration:

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    flex: 0.75,
    style: 'text-align: left;',
    width: 25,
    align: 'center',
    menuDisabled: true,
    bind: {
        text: '{filename}'
    },
    items: [
        {
            handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row) {
                Application.fireEvent("filefunction", view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row);
            },
            getClass: function(v, metadata, r, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                return "x-far fa-file-alt";
            },
            iconCls: 'x-far fa-file-alt',
            // add this for fixed tooltip on the item
            tooltip: 'something',
        }
    ]
}
```

This is a static tooltip, fixed for one action in the column. If you need it dynamic, for example dependant on the record value, you can use the `getClass` function for that for each item:

```
{
    xtype: 'actioncolumn',
    flex: 0.75,
    style: 'text-align: left;',
    width: 25,
    align: 'center',
    menuDisabled: true,
    bind: {
        text: '{filename}'
    },
    items: [
        {
            handler: function(view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row) {
                Application.fireEvent("filefunction", view, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record, row);
            },
            getClass: function(v, meta, r, rowIndex, colIndex, store) {
                // set dynamic tooltip with these two lines
                var tooltip = 'something dynamic';
                meta.tdAttr = Ext.String.format('data-qtip="{0}"', tooltip);
                return "x-far fa-file-alt";
            },
            iconCls: 'x-far fa-file-alt'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: The dynamic one works like a charm, thank you very much Peter :)